# Are there closed manifolds that can be given multiple geometric structures of constant curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-topology

For example, is there a closed differentiable manifold that can be given both a Euclidean structure and a Hyperbolic structure?  If not, is there a reasonably easy proof that no such manifold exists?

Comment: In even dimensions, the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet Theorem will tell you no such manifold exists.

Comment: An excellent question. If you dont get an answer here I suggest you try mathoverflow or write directly to Bill Goldman.

Comment: @GilBor Thanks, I'll give it a couple more days and then try that.

Comment: @TedShifrin And thank you too, that's a good start.

Comment: Asked and answered here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/165868/does-there-exist-a-closed-manifold-that-can-be-given-both-a-euclidean-and-a-hype#comment422730_165868